# How to read from plist to an NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, comparison

i have a pList with this format

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>category</key>
        <string>desert</string>
        <key>numberOfPerson</key>
        <string>3</string>
        <key>recipeImage</key>
        <string>sutlac.jpg</string>
        <key>time</key>
        <string>15 dk</string>
        <key>recipeName</key>
        <string>Puding</string>
        <key>recipeDetail</key>
```

What i need to do is this;   read the recipeIngredients from plist and write it to NSString.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just load your `plist` into an `NSArray` get the dictionary out of it and read the contents from it:

```
NSArray *recipes = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSDictionary *recipe = recipes[0];
NSString *cat = recipe[@"category"];
NSString *recipeName = recipe[@"recipeName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your plist has an array as the outer structure.

You can use the array class method arrayWithContentsOfFile to load the property list into an array.

Then you could use the array's description method, which will return a string display of the contents.

The display method is intended for debugging, so the string you get back isn't intended to use programmatically.

The code might look like this:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: path];
NSString *arrayString = [array description];
NSLog(@"Array string = %@", arrayString);
```